# Add buttons to a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I wish to dynamically add buttons to a specific page. Should I be handling this event in order to do so?

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate",function(event){

});
```

How do I establish which page the event is triggered for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another parameter to the ["on"](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, specifying that it should only trigger for a certain page (or certain class of pages - you can use the entiry jQuery selector syntax there):

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#registration", function() {
```

Comment: What event should I use if I wish to add buttons each time I visit the page? The event pagebeforecreate is only triggered the first time.

Comment: I'd go for [`pagebeforeshow`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) but I see it is deprecated now.